# How to define a threshold from generated H2O Autoencoder / Anomaly Detection Model for Inference in Java API?

Tags: java, h2o, autoencoder, threshold, anomaly-detection

With the latest version of `hex.genmodel` java library, we can get the MSE value. But I need to define the threshold value to identify the anomaly from generated H2O Poco class itself. Even a calculation would be helpful.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define the threshold would be to calculate a say 0.95 quantile of MSE on your training set and use that for a threshold.

Is part of your data labeled - that would open up possibilities for other ways of defining threshold.

Comment: I managed to calculate the threshold from the model and saved it in a DB. So I can now refer to the calculated threshold values ​​using a repo call.